# Dynamic value passing in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Here is a complex query where i need to pass some dates as dynamic to this, As of now i have hardcoded this '2021-08-01' AND '2022-07-31' these 2 dates.

But i have to pass this dates dynamically in such a way that next dates ie, 2022-06 month , thew dates passed will be '2021-07-01' and '2022-06-30' , basically 12 months behind data.

if we take 2022-05 then the passed date should be '2021-06-01' and '2022-05-31'.

How can we achieve this ? Any suggestions or help will be much appreciated.

below is the query for reference

```
WITH base as
(
SELECT created_at as period ,order_number, TRIM(email) as email ,is_first_order
FROM  orders 
WHERE created_at::DATE BETWEEN '2021-08-01' AND '2022-07-31'
)
,base_agg as
(
select TO_CHAR(period,'YYYY-MM') as period
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT email)FILTER(WHERE is_first_order IS TRUE) as new_users
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT order_number)FILTER(WHERE is_first_order IS FALSE) as returning_orders
FROM base
       GROUP BY 1   
)
,base_cumulative as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PERIOD DESC ) as rno
      ,period
      ,new_users
      ,returning_orders
      ,sum("new_users")over (order by "period" asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as "cumulative_total"
from base_agg
 )
 
  SELECT 
    (SELECT period FROM base_cumulative WHERE rno=1) period
   ,(SELECT cumulative_total FROM base_cumulative WHERE rno=1) as cumulated_customers
   ,SUM(returning_orders) as returning_orders
   ,SUM(returning_orders)/NULLIF((SELECT cumulative_total FROM base_cumulative WHERE rno=1),0)  as  rate
 FROM base_cumulative
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the end of current month based on `NOW()` and [some logic](https://database.guide/get-the-last-day-of-the-month-in-postgresql/), the same can be applied with the rest of the calculation

```
select date_trunc('month', now())::date + interval '1 month - 1 day' end_of_this_month, 
    date_trunc('month', now())::date + interval '1 month - 1 day'::interval - '1 year'::interval + '1 day'::interval first_day_of_prev_year_month
    ;
```

Result

```
  end_of_this_month  | first_day_of_prev_year_month
---------------------+------------------------------
 2022-08-31 00:00:00 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00
(1 row)
```